# Как сделать цветную дугу поверх окружности HTML

Tags: html, css, scss, sass

я новичок у верстке, практикуюсь на макете. [image: Задание из макета]

Мой код HTML

[image: код html]

КОД В SCSS:

[image: код в scss]

От что получается у меня, если по логике делать. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно мне сделать эти кусочки дуги?:)

[image: то что получилось у меня]

Comment: Добавьте свой код как код, а не как картинки

Comment: Возможно ответ есть тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705475/Как-сделать-дугу-на-css-или-svg

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать дугу на CSS или SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705475/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение только с таким костылем. Понятно, что цвета и размеры условные, так как в ваших картинках никто разбираться не будет...

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgb(102, 13, 138);
 }
 .circle {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(245, 222, 179, 0);
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  border-radius: 50%;
 
}
.circle p {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: brown;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
.circleIn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200.5px;
  height: 200.5px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <p>3</p>
  <div class="circleIn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не оставляйте так код, вставляйте его в фрагмент кода, чтобы участники могли его запустить и посмотреть на результат.

Comment: Спасибо большое вам и другим кто откликнулся! Все сработало. Очень прошу извините, я только зарегался на этой платформе, по этому еще не разобрался)